# How to recursively count the number of possible increasing sequences from x consecutive numbers?

Tags: java, recursion, sequence

Let integer `x` be the length of the combination of numbers and let there be a range of consecutive integers from 1 to `max`. The sequences must be non-decreasing (the sequence is increasing in general but identical consecutive numbers are possible). Given `x` and `max` how many such sequences are possible?

For example, for `x`=3, `max` = 2 there're 4 possible sequences:

1,1,1

1,1,2

1,2,2

2,2,2

I thought of the following recursive method:

```
public static int howManySorted(int n, int max, int len, int i) {
        if(len > n || i > max) {
            return 0;
        }

        if(len == n && i == max) {
            return 1;
        }

        return howManySorted(n, max, len + 1, i + 1) +
                howManySorted(n, max, len + 1, i) +
                howManySorted(n, max, len, i + 1);
}
```

1. `howManySorted(n, max, len + 1, i + 1)` refers to the case where the sequence length is increased by one and the next number is bigger than the previous by one.
2. `howManySorted(n, max, len + 1, i)` refers to the case where the sequence length is increased by one and the next number is the same as the previous by one.

I do realize there's a problem with my recursive formula because in such sequences the difference between the adjacent numbers is at most `1`. So I decided to add another call `howManySorted(n, max, len, i + 1)` which would compensate for such cases but this still doesn't produce the intended results. What am I doing wrong?

I call this method from `main` like this `howManySorted(n, max, 1, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say `len = 10` and `max = 5`.

Note that since we're not interested in the actual solutions, only the count, the result for range 2-5 is the same as the result for range 1-4.

For the first digit, we can choose a number 1-5, then:

1. recursive call with `len = 9`, limiting number range to 1-5, i.e. `max = 5`
2. recursive call with `len = 9`, limiting number range to 2-5, i.e. `max = 4`
3. recursive call with `len = 9`, limiting number range to 3-5, i.e. `max = 3`
4. recursive call with `len = 9`, limiting number range to 4-5, i.e. `max = 2`
5. recursive call with `len = 9`, limiting number range to 5-5, i.e. `max = 1`

Sum up the counts returned by the recursive calls. That is the result of this call.

When `len = 1`, there are `max` solutions, so return `max` as the count.

When `max = 1`, there is only one solution, regardless of `len`, so return `1` as the count.

I'll leave the actual coding up to you.

Comment: is this the correct implementation of your answer? It does work on the input of `len=3, n=2` but doesn't work on other inputs (for example, for `len=2, n=3` it returns `5` instead of `6`. `public static int howManySorted(int max, int len) {
        if(max == 1)
            return 1;
        if(len == 1)
            return max;

        return howManySorted(max - 1, len - 1) +
                howManySorted(max, len - 1);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int howManySorted(int n, int max)
{
    return howManySorted(n, 1, max);
}

private static int howManySorted(int n, int min, int max)
{
    if (n == 1)
       return max - min + 1;
    if (min == max)
       return 1;
    return howManySorted(n, min + 1, max) + howManySorted(n-1, min, max);
}
```